# Problem with app groups in 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, groups

After upgrading to 20.04 the app drawer freaks out when I close a group. I have only 2 pages, but after I open and close a group the system freezes for a second and than shows as if I have more pages than i really have. I can't access these pages as they don't really exist. And if I try to open and close a group again the entire system freezes and I'm forced to reboot. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gkfr.png)

Comment: Installed extensions are the first usual suspects for issues with gnome shell. Disable them, restart the system, and then reenable them one by one until the problem reappears to identify the faulty extension.